# preg_match_all How to get all links?

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get all images links with preg_match_all those that begin with http://i.ebayimg.com/ and ends with .jpg , from page that I'm scraping.. I Can not do it correctly... :( I tried this but this is not what i need...:

```
preg_match_all('/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/', $contentas, $img_link);
```

Same problem is with normal links... I don't know how to write preg_match_all to this:

```
<a class="link--muted" href="http://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/details.html?id=218930381&daysAfterCreation=7&isSearchRequest=true&withImage=true&scopeId=C&categories=Limousine&damageUnrepaired=NO_DAMAGE_UNREPAIRED&zipcode=&fuels=DIESEL&ambitCountry=DE&maxPrice=11000&minFirstRegistrationDate=2006-01-01&makeModelVariant1.makeId=3500&makeModelVariant1.modelId=20&pageNumber=1" data-touch="hover" data-touch-wrapper=".cBox-body--resultitem">
```

Thank you very much!!!

**UPDATE**
I'm trying from here: 
`http://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/search.html?isSearchRequest=true&scopeId=C&makeModelVariant1.makeId=1900&makeModelVariant1.modelId=10&makeModelVariant1.modelDescription=&makeModelVariantExclusions%5B0%5D.makeId=&categories=Limousine&minSeats=&maxSeats=&doorCount=&minFirstRegistrationDate=2006-01-01&maxFirstRegistrationDate=&minMileage=&maxMileage=&minPrice=&maxPrice=11000&minPowerAsArray=&maxPowerAsArray=&maxPowerAsArray=PS&minPowerAsArray=PS&fuels=DIESEL&minCubicCapacity=&maxCubicCapacity=&ambitCountry=DE&zipcode=&q=&climatisation=&airbag=&daysAfterCreation=7&withImage=true&adLimitation=&export=&vatable=&maxConsumptionCombined=&emissionClass=&emissionsSticker=&damageUnrepaired=NO_DAMAGE_UNREPAIRED&numberOfPreviousOwners=&minHu=&usedCarSeals=` get cars links and image links and all information, with information is everything fine, my script works good, but i have problem with scraping images and links.. here is my script :

```
<?php

        $id= $_GET['id'];
        $user= $_GET['user'];
        $login=$_COOKIE['login'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT pavadinimas,nuoroda,kuras,data,data_new from mobile where vartotojas='$user' and id='$id'");
    $rezultatas=mysql_fetch_row($query);

    $url = "$rezultatas[1]";

    $info = file_get_contents($url); 

function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
$data = stristr($data, $start); 
$data = substr($data, strlen($start));
$stop = stripos($data, $end);
$data = substr($data, 0, $stop);
return $data;
  }
     //turinio iskirpimas
    $turinys = scrape_between($info, '<div class="g-col-9">', '<footer class="footer">');
     //filtravimas naikinami mokami top skelbimai
    $contentas = preg_replace('/<div class="cBox-body cBox-body--topResultitem".*?>(.*?)<\/div>/', '' ,$turinys);
    //filtravimas baigtas

      preg_match_all('/<span class="h3".*?>(.*?)<\/span>/',$contentas,$pavadinimas); 

      preg_match_all('/<span class="u-block u-pad-top-9 rbt-onlineSince".*?>(.*?)<\/span>/',$contentas,$data); 

      preg_match_all('/<span class="u-block u-pad-top-9".*?>(.*?)<\/span>/',$contentas,$miestas);

      preg_match_all('/<span class="h3 u-block".*?>(.*?)<\/span>/', $contentas, $kaina);

      preg_match_all('/<a[A-z0-9-_:="\.\/ ]+href="(http:\/\/suchen.mobile.de\/fahrzeuge\/[^"]*)"[A-z0-9-_:="\.\/ ]\s*>\s*<div/s', $contentas, $matches);

   print_r($pavadinimas);
   print_r($data);
   print_r($miestas);
   print_r($kaina);
   print_r($result);
   print_r($matches);

   ?>
```

Comment: could you provide an input and desired ouput please? because that it's not very clear

Comment: Still not clear. Instead of adding your code, please add what you want to have at the end of your script. do you want an array of all `a` and `img` tag that contains url : **http://suchen.mobile.de/.....jpg** ? Do you want them in 2 arrays or 2 separate arrays?

Comment: Yes, I want all array of all a href, and than all array of img src.. for example: 
$all_images = preg_match_all("HERE select all images links that contains url  http://i.ebayimg.com/HERE ALWAYS DIFERENT TEXT/109.JPG"); 
$all_ahref = preg_match_all("HERE is all ahref links that starts http://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/"); and then i do for() and put everyting in table! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** To capture `src` attribute starting by `http://i.ebayimg.com/` of all `img` tags :

regex : `/src=\"((?:http|https):\\/\\/i.ebayimg.com\\/.+?.jpg)\"/i`

Here is an example :

```php
$re = "/src=\"((?:http|https):\\/\\/i.ebayimg.com\\/.+?.jpg)\"/i"; 
$str = "codeOfHTMLPage"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Check it in live : [here](https://regex101.com/r/dZ9eR3/4)

**If you want to be sure that you capture this url on an `img` tag then use this regex** (keep in mind that performance will decrease if page is very long) :

```
$re = "/<img(?:.*?)src=\"((?:http|https):\\/\\/i.ebayimg.com\\/.+?.jpg)\"/i";
```

**2.** To capture `href` attribute starting by `http://i.ebayimg.com/` of all `a` tags :

regex : `/href=\"((?:http|https):\\/\\/suchen.mobile.de\\/fahrzeuge\\/.+?.jpg)\"/i`

Here is an example :

```php
$re = "/href=\"((?:http|https):\\/\\/suchen.mobile.de\\/fahrzeuge\\/.+?.jpg)\"/i; 
$str = "codeOfHTMLPage"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Check it in live : [here](https://regex101.com/r/yB5oC5/3)

**If you want to be sure that you capture this url on an `a` tag then use this regex** (keep in mind that performance will decrease if page is very long) :

```
$re = "/<a(?:.*?)href=\"((?:http|https):\\/\\/suchen.mobile.de\\/fahrzeuge\\/.+?.jpg)\"/i";
```

Comment: 1. This not working. 2. I need to get <a href links, example is in my question. AND I need images links thaht ends with .jpg its not same, can you help me??

Comment: Thanks.. but why <img(?:.*?)/src=\"((?:http|https):\\/\\/i.ebayimg.com\\/.+?.jpg)\"/i this not working??

Answer (score 1):

More handy with DOMDocument:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($yourURL);

$imgNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

$result = [];

foreach ($imgNodes as $imgNode) {
    $src = $imgNode->getAttribute('src');
    $urlElts = parse_url($src);
    $ext = strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $urlElts['path'])));
    if ($ext == 'jpg' && $urlElts['host'] == 'i.ebayimg.com')
        $result[] = $src;
}

print_r($result);
```

To get "normal" links, use the same way (DOMDocument + parse_url).

Comment: 1. This not working. 2. I need to get <a href links, example is in my question. AND I need images links thaht ends with .jpg its not same, can you help me??